# Software/Tool for Form Designing to be user on cross platform

Tags: cross-platform, user-interface, forms

We need recommendation on any software/tool/online tool for designing forms. 
Below are the conditions which should be matched:

1. Form designed can be user cross platform Web/Windows/Andriod/iOS
2. Form designed can be used offline or online. Offline means we can download the form designed and can use in our application.
3. Data from the form should not be saved on third party tools used instead should be saved on our local database.
4. Form designer tool should have various options for controls like file upload, draw on image control (can select image and draw on it).
5. Form designer tool can be either free or licences.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you open to browser-based HTML forms? That sounds easiest. If not, look at Qt